# Suprema BioMini Plus Scanner CSharpSample Code in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to test the Suprema BioMini Plus Scanner CSharpSample Code that comes with the sdk but it's giving me this error:

> Enrollment was not finished. Reason: NoScanner

I have installed the driver correctly, using the driver documentation instructions. Can anyone tell me exactly the names of the dll I needed to add and the folder In which each of this dll(s) should be?

Secondly, what is the correct library name I needed to add to the project as reference?

Comment: What sdk? It's worth to add proper tag (library name) to question or give us  link to what you are trying to do. Have you tried to google for error message?

Comment: @Sinatr, the sdk is "FreeFingerprintVerificationSDKSetup"

Comment: Please show some code of what you are doing. Which API are you using? If you share that here it will help everyone to understand what you are up to.

Comment: @JosephMwema, this texteditor character limit is too small to contain the code.

Comment: How can I add these two import statement to my project reference        using Neurotec.Biometrics;
using Neurotec.Gui;

Comment: Your code uses Neurotechnology SDK. Do you have that installed in your development platform? If not you can get it from their source here www.neurotechnology.com